# Calling DataGridView's Rows.Clear() more than one time throws exception

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, datagridview

I am having this issue.

I have implemented a custom class in `C#` extending `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView`.
I need to programmatically rebuild the `Rows` list, clearing it and adding the rows again (I am not using a `BindingSource`/Databases or anything like it, nor I need those).

The issue is: when I call my method `Rearrange()` the first time it works, the next times I get an `Exception` in the `this.Rows.Clear()` line (Sorry my system is in Italian):

> Eccezione non gestita di tipo 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Ulteriori informazioni: Operazione non riuscita. Impossibile eseguire il commit o l'annullamento della modifica al valore della cella.

Here is how I wrote the `CustomDataGridView` method `Rearrange()`:

```
public void Rearrange()
{
    List<Alarm> list = alarms.GetAllarms();

    this.Rows.Clear();

    if (list.Count > 0)
    {
        DateTime lastdate = list[0].date;
        Rows.Add(new DataGridMarker(lastdate));
        Rows.Add(new DataGridMarker(lastdate));

        foreach (Alarm alarm in list)
        {
            if (lastdate < alarm.data)
            {
                lastdate = alarm.data;
                this.Rows.Add(new DataGridMarker(lastdate));
            }
            this.Rows.Add(new CustomDataGridViewRow(alarm.type, new object[] {
                alarm.superCode + "-" + alarm.code,
                alarm.time.ToString(@"hh\:mm"),
                alarm.description,
                alarm.details
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to understand what I'm doing wrong... I have set my datagridview and all the columns, rows and cells to be readonly I can't figure out why should it commit some editing.

Could you help me out to fix this?

Thank you very much :3

Comment: could you tell which line of code is throwing the `InvalidOperationException`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it was clear (edited). I tried to explain that `this.Rows.Clear()` throws the exception (see title), this behaviour is weird :(

Comment: Can you set the debugger on that line and see if Rows is null the 2nd time?

Comment: No it is not null, I already checked it.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your datagridview is not in edit mode. Adding the following line before the rows.clear did the trick for me

```
datagridview1.EndEdit()
```